# Change JavaScript variable value by passing new values inside URL ( GET request )

Tags: javascript, url, get, mapbox-gl-js

I have an i frame which has a src called map.php.

```
  <iframe src= "map.php " ></iframe>
```

Inside map.php i have a variable called map. I want to change the value of  "center " inside the map variable to something new when the src load up

map.php (javascript)

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({


 center: [115.83333, -32.01667], 
    
 
});
```

So my question is whether i can pass some parameter values along with src = map.php to change the center value

example. ( Just my concept )

```
 <iframe  src= "map.php/parameter center[new values] " ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass values in query param by constructing the url like this:

`map.php/parameter?cx=115.83333&cy=-32.01667`

Again in the php script you can access these values from query params using
`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Just parse,extract and use the values inside php file.

Comment: Hey , Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, this does not change anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

What @diwakersurya said was right , but you had to use the GET. I am posting a full answer for anyone who is stuck.

php

```
$str1 = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$x = $_GET['cx'];
$y = $_GET['cy'];
```